# Get the text inside HTML which was set using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get the id of the table row from which a button belongs and came up with printing the id of the row(which is the same as the IDs from the database) in a `<span>` element inside a modal box. It works perfectly but then when I try to get the text in the `<span>` tag using DOM, it is empty.   I tried using AJAX to post the data but I can't seem to get it work so I resorted to this.

Here is the javascript/jQuery

```
$('#ViewModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) { //Fires when modal is opened
        var $modal = $(this),
            inventory_id = e.relatedTarget.id;

        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'view_items.php',
            data: {inventory_id: trId},
            success: function(data) {
                $modal.find('.inventory_id').html(trId);
            }
        });
    })
```

Here is my HTML and PHP:

```
    <div id="ViewModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ItemView" aria-hidden="true">
             <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;  </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="ItemView">Item view</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <span id=id class='inventory_id hidden'></span>
                    <?php
                        //query here to get the record based on the text in the element
                        $doc = new DOMDocument();
                        $id = $doc->getElementById('id');
                        $inventory_id = $id;
                        $echo $inventory_id //returns an empty value
                        //bind to parameters
                        $result = $query->get_result();
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
                        {
                            //I'm going to echo result here
                        }
                    ?>
    </div>
```

Am I doing the right thing? Or should I just use another approach to pass the variable value to PHP?

Comment: You can't really pass a variable to PHP the way you're doing. You can't run PHP after javascript.  Just because you have an ajax call, doesn't mean it will update the php.  All of that PHP code runs before your ajax call.  You'd have to do all of that PHP stuff inside of your `view_items.php` script and return the results on success

Comment: @ntgCleaner Oh, thank you for the information. Would you mind giving an example?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing in your `view_items.php` script, but basically, just do your `mysqli` calls in that script.  Once you return the calls successfully in the php script, place them into a json object then return them  via an `echo` or something similar.  You can capture all of that `data` in your ajax success and do whatever you want in javascript

Comment: @ntgCleaner thank you!

Comment: You got it, good luck!